# Array does not get filled with function

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain to me why array(defined outside function) does not get filled by the function. So I could use it for other functions

My code:

```
var points = [];
var eilutes = [];
var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM ping', function(err, eilutes){

    //if (err) throw err;

    for (var i in eilutes){
        points.push(eilutes[i]);
    }
    console.log(points[1]);  //// Result is returned
    console.log(eilutes[1]); //// Result is returned
});
console.log(points[1]); //// promts: undefined
console.log(eilutes[1]); //// promts: undefined
```

Comment: `query()` is asynchronous, that's why there's a callback parameter.

Comment: Also, `eilutes` is an array `[]` not an object `{}`. Don't use `for-in` to iterate arrays! Use an incremental `for` loop instead.  `for (var i=0; i<eilutes.length; i++)`

Comment: I declared: `eilutes = [];` How to callback an array?

Answer (score 0):

Because query is asynchronous, so the code in the anonymous function is not called in whatever function this is a part of.

Comment: @jbabey Well, I think I made a mistake not showing full code. I am doing two queries after that I alter query results in code, I have managed two do this with multiple query statement (not very secure). So I think callback is not very good idea...